# Is "midstep" a word?

Tags: word-usage

I've seen several examples of words starting with mid, such as midstream, midmorning etc. Microsoft word always flags midstep as incorrect while greenlighting the other examples. The context I plan to use it in is for a science fiction novel. Something like this: His foot caught midstep.

Comment: Please include the research you've done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic. (And citing what Word or some other text editor flags is not "research".)

Comment: First time I've used this site so I wasn't aware there was another place to ask questions like this, that said I don't see my question being out of place on these forums. I wouldn't have asked were it answerable via commonly available channels, in fact it isn't as evidenced by your inability to provide a useful answer. Did a fair bit of trawling online, including this site and didn't come up with anything conclusive, turns out it's a niche case as the helpful poster below answered, whaddya know.

Comment: if you're not sure you can always separate mid and the word you want to use it with. Mid is an independent word not only a prefix.

Comment: The close-vote reason is not wonderfully phrased. Here, you have shown no evidence of research. A Google search for <midstep + meaning> gave me the Wiktionary definition first and third. Hence the close-votes are valid. If you'd posted the Wiktionary definition (as Josh61 does for you) and asked whether the fact that say ODO, AHDEL, Collins and RHK Webster's don't list the word makes the Wiktionary licensing untrustworthy, the question would be fine.

Comment: When Word flags a closed prefix form such as _midstep_, that doesn't mean it would flag the hyphenated form _mid-step_ (which means the same thing). In fact, Word indiscriminately accepts almost any "mid-" word as long as you hyphenate it. You can demonstrate this by typing the following sentence into Word: "Word objects to midstep but not to mid-step, mid-money, mid-otter, or mid-middle." Absurdly, only _midstep_ will get the red squiggle treatment. But including or omitting the hyphen when using "mid-" as a prefix is purely a matter of style, not of the word's existence as a "real word."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a common term. That's probably why the spelling checker flags it:

***[Midstep:](https://www.google.it/search?q=midstep%20meaning&rlz=1C9BKJA_enIT606IT607&oq=midstep%20meaning%20&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.4669j0j8&hl=it&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8)*** (adverb)

> - During a step.
>
>   - 2007 July 22, Caroline H. Dworin, “Love Letters to a Dowager of a Muse”, in New York Times: 
>       *Moody, often blurred and set in rooms cast with bohemian clutter, these images capture tenants in their downbeat moments, mouths half-open, eyes half-closed, midstep or midconversation*.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=midstep&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmidstep%3B%2Cc0): ***midstep***

Usage examples:

From "[When I fall in love](https://books.google.it/books?id=tp7wEFZjVu4C&pg=PA291&dq=%22midstep%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiC68LHysvOAhUEbhQKHRUsAvcQ6AEIOzAF#v=onepage&q=%22midstep%22&f=false)" by Lynn Kurland - 2007:

> She hesitated in midstep thanks to the glares she caught the moment she was noticed. What she tried not to notice, however, was how Rhys smoothly…

From "[The gift](https://books.google.it/books?id=2puDuvXSGsoC&pg=PA225&dq=%22midstep%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjpicSay8vOAhXKwBQKHVnWD5c4ChDoAQhOMAk#v=onepage&q=%22midstep%22&f=false)" by Richard Paul Evans - 2007:‎

> Steve paused midstep, a nearly indiscernible smile crossing his lips. Then he turned and looked at the old man.

Comment: Part of the trouble I had with looking up this particular definition through google is a lot of the provided sources aren't very reputable, probably because it's such an uncommon term. But seeing it used in the provided works lends some credibility to its use and eases my mind, thank you!